# Inconveniente con Datepicker de bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, vb.net, datepicker

Actualmente estoy intentando utilizar un datepicker de bootstrap, el mismo se muestra correctamente, el tema es cuando voy a seleccionar años o meses, no se porque se muestra mal de la siguiente manera.
[image: Imagen con calendario sin abrir meses ni años]

[image: Al abrir los años o meses para buscar se muestran así]

Mi pagina esta consumiendo un MasterPage el cual se encuentra configurado de la siguiente manera

```html
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="Master.MasterPage" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Master.css">
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="wrapper" class="active">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
                    <loggedintemplate>
                        <%= ArmaMenu() %>
                    </loggedintemplate>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid" id="FormularioContenido">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Funciones.js"></script>
```

Y mi pagina donde estoy consumiendo o tratando de utilizar el datepicker es el siguiente código.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="CartaSaldo.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
               <input type='text' class="form-control" />
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
          });
      </script>
   </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

desconozco con que versión de bootstrap estás trabajando, aunque hay dos formas para obtener un datepicker, la primera, por medio de un input de tipo date

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="date" />
  </body>
</html>
```

En esta solución, yo estoy utilizando una versión de bootstrap 4.6, te dejo en la cabecera, los que implemento.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            });
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.2/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.1.2/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
           <input id="min" name="min" type="text" /> 
         </div>
      </div>
      
   </div>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Saludos